# Cygwin Patch fails

Tags: 7, version-control

I have failed to get my first patch to implement.  I loaded cygwin, maneuver to the directory, and enter patch -p0 < `ThePatchName`.patch

Cygwin returns   bash: patch: command not found

I searched the cygwin/bin directory and there is an executable for pathk.exe, but not patch.exe.  I cannot find documentation on these commands at cygwin, so I do not know if they are the same. Does anyone know about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not quite a Drupal question. That said, patch for Cygwin needs to be installed. Rerun your Cygwin "setup" program, and search for "patch". In my setup, it is under the "Utils" category. Once you find it, select it and then hit "Next" to finish the install. It should be available.

Comment: You answered while I was writing my answer.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

What I did:

Patch is not automatically installed.  I went to cygwin.com/install.html, selected cygwin packages menu item, reloaded setup.exe and found patch buried in a long list of commands.  after installing it, everything worked.

There are a couple of problems to watch out for using cygwin.

Moving to the directory in using this linux tool is different than DOS. Enter this: cd /cygdrive/c/theRestofthePath.  Note that it does not recognize spaces unless they are preceded by a backslash.

The patch command is: patch -p0

Answer (score 0):

Use: `apt-cyg install patch`. (It's in its own package.)